# Error calling stored procedure from PHP

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a problem with this code in Oracle:

```
create or replace procedure InsertarEntertNotica (IDSUBTOPIC out varchar,
  TEXT out varchar,IMAGE out varchar,STADE out varchar,TITT out varchar)
is
  idS varchar2(3) := IDSUBTOPIC;
  txt varchar2(4000) := TEXT;
  img varchar2(100) := IMAGE;
  st varchar2(2) := STADE;
  fech varchar2(30);
  tit varchar2(300) := TITT;
  hor date;
begin
  SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YY') into fech FROM DUAL;
  SELECT SYSDATE into hor FROM DUAL;
  insert into ENTERTAIMENT (IDSUBTEMA,TEXTO,IMAGEN,ESTADO,FECHA,TITULO,HORA) 
    values (idS,txt,img,st,fech,tit,hor);
end;
```

When I create this SP, I have not problem, but when I execute it I have this problem

```
Error starting at line : 377 in command -
execute InsertarEntertNotica('ET','Texto de la Noticia Proc','','No','Noticia con Procedimiento')
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 28:
PLS-00363: expression 'ET' cannot be used as an assignment target
ORA-06550: line 1, column 33:
PLS-00363: expression 'Texto de la Noticia Proc' cannot be used as an assignment target
ORA-06550: line 1, column 60:
PLS-00363: expression '<null>' cannot be used as an assignment target
ORA-06550: line 1, column 63:
PLS-00363: expression 'No' cannot be used as an assignment target
ORA-06550: line 1, column 68:
PLS-00363: expression 'Noticia con Procedimiento' cannot be used as an assignment target
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
```

Comment: the error is on line 377 but you have not shown 377 lines of code.  Also I find your use of VARCHAR as parameters which you immediately redefine as VARCHAR2 inside the procedure to be odd.

Comment: Why have you declared the parameters as OUT, when you seem to intend to pass and use values, rather then set and return them to the caller? And why have local variables that just take the parameter values? Do you really need to do this through a procedure at all?

Answer (score 0):

You've declared all your formal parameters as `OUT`, which means when you call the procedure you must pass updatable variables, not fixed string values. [The documentation shows how `IN/OUT` works.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS659)

You can just change them to `IN`. You also don't need any of the local variables:

```
create or replace procedure InsertarEntertNotica (IDSUBTOPIC in varchar,
  TEXT in varchar,IMAGE in varchar,STADE in varchar,TITT in varchar)
is
begin
  insert into ENTERTAIMENT (IDSUBTEMA, TEXTO, IMAGEN, ESTADO, FECHA, TITULO, HORA) 
  values (IDSUBTOPIC, TEXT, IMAGE, STADE, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YY'),
    TITT, SYSDATE);
end;
```

If you are going to have local variables then names that distinguish from the parameter names would be good. It's common to use a prefix to distinguish, e.g. `p_text` for the parameter and `l_text` for the local variable.

Using `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YY')` looks wrong for a couple of reasons. Two digit years can cause unexpected results, as well as the infamous Y2K problems. If `FECHA` is a DATE column rather than VARCHAR2(8), as it should be, then you are implicitly converting that string back to a date using the session NLS settings - which is dangerous, and will only work at all if the session *happens* to also be DD/MM/YY. If you're really trying to store today's date with the time as midnight then you should use `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` instead. Although not sure why you'd store that as a separate column to `HORA` anyway.